# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException error on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, propertynotfoundexception

I have a `List<Products>` which contains data of my products table. On a servlet I am getting this `List<Products>`. I am passing this list to JSP by following code:

```
List<Products>Products=new SessionBeanClass().DisplayProducts(arr);
request.setAttribute("Products",Products);
request.getRequestDispatcher("sample2.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And I am displaying data of LIST on JSP by following code:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope['Products']}" var="emp" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>  ${emp.getPrice()} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

But when I write like this

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope['Products']}" var="emp" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>  ${emp.Price()} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

It shows me an error

> **javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException 'Price' not found**

Why?

Answer (score 2):

change

```
${emp.Price()}
```

to

```
${emp.price}
```

Comment: thanks sir but why it was not working

Comment: JSTL looksup for standard accessor method for property, `Price()` isn't actually a resolvable property that way